# create two classes with pthread create and get access to each other in cpp

Tags: c++, class, object, pthreads

```
 #include <pthread.h>

class Controller{
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        void Run();
        int getX(){return x;};
        int getY(){return y;};
        int getXSpeed(){return xSpeed;};
        int getYSpeed(){return ySpeed;};
        void setLocation(int x2, int y2);
};

class AutomaticControl {
  private:
    int lastX;
    int lastY;

    Controller contr;
  public:
    AutomaticControl(Controller controller){
        contr = controller;
    }
    void *Run(void);
    static void *Run_helper(void *context){return ((AutomaticControl *)context)->Run();};
};

class Ballsearch {
  private:
    Controller contr;
  public:
    Ballsearch(Controller controller){
        contr = controller;
    };
    void *Run();
    static void *Run_helper(void *context){return ((Ballsearch *)context)->Run();};
};
```

In my header file are three classes mentioned: Controller AutomaticControl and Ballsearch.
Now I want to create two threads: these are ballsearch.Run() and AutomaticControl.Run()
I created it like in the following code.
This works.
I use the controller object in the ballsearch funktion Run(). This changes x and y.
After I done this. There is an other thread active. The AutomaticControl Run() function.
It als use the controller object with getX() and getY(). 
If I use it in AutmaticControl there are not the values which I expected. There should be the values which mentioned in the ballsearch function Run().
How can I solve this Problem.

Here is the complete code in cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


Controller contr1;

Ballsearch ballsearch(contr1);
AutomaticControl automaticcontr (contr1);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Controller contrl;
    contrl.Run();
    return 0;
}



void Controller::Run(){
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,&Ballsearch::Run_helper,&ballsearch); // &ballsearch
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,&AutomaticControl::Run_helper,&automaticcontr); //&automaticcontr
    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
    cout << "hello"<<endl;
}


void Controller::setLocation(int x2, int y2){
    x = x2;
    y = y2;
    cout << "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" << endl;
    cout  <<  " x-Position:    " << x <<"    y -Position:   " << y <<endl;
    cout << "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" << endl;
}


void *Ballsearch::Run() {

    cout << "ballsearch   run" << endl;
    contr.setLocation(20,30);
    delay(3000);
}

void *AutomaticControl::Run() {

    cout << "AutomaticControl  run " << endl;
    cout << "* Start Automatic Control *" << endl;
    delay(1000);
    lastX = contr.getX();
    lastY = contr.getY();

    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout  <<  " contr.getX()  " << lastX << "    contr.getY()  " << lastY <<endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162549/how-to-access-the-same-data-using-threads

Comment: you can't test it, because it's written on visual studio.
I use it with the raspberry pi.

Comment: Basically, if you have 2 threads sharing a piece of information, you want to either use a messaging system to notify each thread that the data changed, and leave that task of updating it to a single thread, OR share access to that data and use a mutex to avoid concurrent access.

Comment: I tend to go for the 1st solution, because of separation of concerns, but it really depends on your setup.

Comment: i have found my mistake: i changed this: contr->setLocation in Ballsearch. than i changed this:>>Controller * contr;>>AutomaticControl(Controller &controller){>>contr = &controller;>>}>> in AutomaticControl AND Ballsearch. than i changed this :  >> Ballsearch ballsearch(*this);>>AutomaticControl automaticcontr(*this);>> in the Controller::Run() function;

Comment: If you fixed it, I suggest witing an answer. It is ok to answer your own question if nobody else did it correctly. Don't forget to accept it when the timer runs out.

Comment: where can I answer my own question?

Comment: There's a form below which let you input answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found my mistake: 
i changed this: 
`contr->setLocation` in Ballsearch.

then i changed this:

```
Controller * contr;
AutomaticControl(Controller &controller){
contr = &controller;
}
```

in AutomaticControl AND Ballsearch.

then i changed this:

```
Ballsearch ballsearch(*this);
AutomaticControl automaticcontr(*this);
```

in the Controller::Run() function;

The `Controller::Run()` function includes the `ptread_create`